Library Compile time configuration
I'm working on a static library project in Visual Studio 2022, and I want to support per-project compile time configurations. My goal would be to have a header file in the projects that reference this library and to have this header included in the library so that it can define compile time settings
One way I found to do this is to use the #if __has_include() preprocessor macro and then include the configuration file if found, and then the user would have to compile the library specifying the config file path as an additional include directory.
However, I'm having some issues when trying to implement this. I'm referencing this library in another project of the same solution, and I'd like to, if possible, add the additional build directory to the library when building this application so that it compiles with the configs without having to change any of the library properties.
I've tried using Pre-Build events and other Visual Studio project properties to make this work, but so far, I haven't been successful. Any help on how to achieve this or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Might be simpler for the user of the library to include the config header themselves before including your libraries header?

There is similar thread that point to : #pragma include_alias.
Is there a pragma directive for include directories?
But it makes a simple thing complicated.
I did not find any other related compiler options.
You can let users configure the Include Folder directories themselves.
If the purpose is to make it easier for users to use your library, there are package management tools such as vcpkg or NuGet.
